# Changing label in one ViewController from a button in another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm new to Obj-c, and I've been trying to figure this out and I've found a few posts, but I couldn't get the solutions to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

So here's the setup. I have a viewcontroller with a button in it. That button, when touched, is supposed to update the label in another viewcontroller.

This is what I've done so far.

**VC1:**
I've set the property in header of VC1:

```
MainScene *msc;
```

I have this method in implementation file being called upon clicking of the button:

```
-(void) button {
        [msc updateLabel];
}
```

**VC2:**
Here is the method updateLabel.

```
-(void)updateLabel {
    label.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2LF", points];
}
```

I also have the method in the header:

```
-(void)updateLabel;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

From `VC1` you first create an instance of the `ViewController VC2`.

And before you present it set the string value on VC2 property.

Answer (score 0):

you have just define a property in the VC1 named msc, but you have not assign it to any instance of VC2  so when you try call the method `updateLabel` nothing happened.
in your case I assume VC2 is the parent viewcontroller and VC1 is present by VC2. so you need setup a protocol and a delegate in VC1 to udate the label of vc2.

add these in VC1 head file:

```
@protocol VC1Delegate <NSObject>
-(void)updateLabel;
@end
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<VC1Delegate> delegate;
```

and set the VC1's delegate = VC2 while presenting the VC1

if VC1 is parent viewcontroller things will be easier, just use `[msc updateLabel];` after you asign the instance value to msc.

Comment: Thanks. I added those into VC1, hold on accidently published. typing now

Comment: Okay, but VC1 is a scrollview. There is a button to make VC1 visible, and then there is a button contained by the scrollview that should chagne the text on VC2. So basically it is just a visibility toggle. So how would I set VC1s delegate = to VC2?

Comment: @AlbertKornas you need clear the relationship between VC1 and VC2.the button make VC1 visible, where is it? VC2? if it is in VC2 then VC2 is the parent of VC1. if it's not in VC2 then you must have another VC as root VC. do all these changes in root VC's code.

Comment: okay I just watched a video on protocols and delegates and I understand it better now, but I'm still having trouble getting this to work. My two viewcontrollers are called "Shop" and "MainScene". In MainScene, Shop is made visible when a button is clicked, and then on the shop scene there is a button that fires "UpdateLabel", and that should change the text in the label on MainScene. So, I've declared everything you put in your post, the protocal and the property. I also have the buttons method declared. In the MainScene header I conformed to the protocol by doing <ShopDelegate> ...

Comment: @highwings then in the MainScene implementation file I have the method "UpdateLabel", that changes the text of the label. In the shop implementation file I am calling the delegate by saying "[self.delegate updateLabel];".  I'm not sure what else I am missing

Comment: @AlbertKornas did you assign the shop's delegate to MainScene? if not , then self.delegate is nil thus "[self.delegate updateLabel];" won't do any thing.

Comment: Yep that was the part I missed! I have an NSLog in UpdateLabel that is fired every time the button is clicked which is now working. But, the label still doesn't change. I think I assigned it correctly, I put this in the buttons method (this is in Shop.m):           MainScene *msc = [[MainScene alloc]init];
       self.delegate = msc; . For some reason the label doesn't change though. @highwing

Comment: @AlbertKornas that's not correct. the msc should already exist you don't need alloc init it again, otherwise you just create another empty instance, not the one you seen on the screen.`In MainScene, Shop is made visible when a button is clicked`,you should set shop's delegate here, when the shop is made visible. it should in mainscene's code and should be sth like this: `shopVC.delegate=self;`

Comment: @highwings okay that makes sense, but then I get "property delegate is not found on object of type Shop", unless I alloc init it, but then updateLabel just isn't ever called (no NSLog output). I'd like to paste the code into here but it comes out unformatted. Basically it is just a void, and it uses the ".visible" property to toggle. Like this. shopScrollView.visible = YES; If that has to do with anything. Everything is imported correctly.

Comment: @AlbertKornas you're mess around view and viewcontroller, if you're just showing the shopScrollView, then what controller it is under? maybe still under the mainScene controller?

Comment: the actual scrollview element is contained by mainscene, but the buttons inside the scrollview are held in the Shop class. The visibility toggle is contained in a button method in MainScene.m, and then the buttons inside the scrollview are contained in Shop like I mentioned.

Comment: @AlbertKornas you need distinguish the different between view and viewcontroller. So far from your description I believe you only need one viewcontroller to control both view (MainScene and Shop).

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I see what you're saying. I'm using SpriteBuilder (cocos2d) to build the interfaces. I assigned the scrollview a different class (not mainscene) to handle the buttons and everything. Would it be possible to just have the buttons on MainScene? If so that would be great. I'll try to do it now

Comment: okay I just did it however the label still doesn't update to the correct points amount. I set up an NSLog that tells me the points amount and it works perfectly, but I'm not sure why the labels text isn't updating. Any ideas? I'm going to keep trying but I'm not sure what else I could possibly do. Here's a picture, I commented it out and replaced the variables with something easier to understand http://i.imgur.com/O2nhgmB.jpg?1?7605

Comment: I think I messed up the tagging on the last post. I honestly am having trouble thinking of a solution. I assume that since the NSLog works, it must be something with the scrollview not being able to contact MainScene? Not sure..

Comment: @AlbertKornas if label is a standard UILabel,you should use `label.text` instead of `label.string`, I don't even know there's a `string` in UILabel.

Comment: it's a CCLabelTTF but I am using 'label.string' in other methods to update other labels and it's been working just fine. Hmm..

Comment: could it have something to do with the fact that MainScene is loading the scrollview element from a different view? http://i.imgur.com/ajppRUh.jpg?2?6430 heres what it looks like. and here is what I have in MainScene. http://i.imgur.com/knp2ACD.jpg?1?9525 Thanks so far for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AlbertKornas you really need upload more codes for me to check the problem. I don't know how you defined the label, since NSLOG is working, the only possible problem should be in the label itself.

Comment: I also tried to make a sprite invisible under the same button, that didn't work either. I also want to note that the actual scrollview buttons and text are designed in a CCLayer (scrollShop.ccb), and then scrollShop.ccb is loaded in MainScene under the scrollview element. [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/B8IePed.jpg?1?2395) . [And then here is the layer that all the buttons are in, scrollShop.ccb](http://i.imgur.com/v5RQoDv.jpg?2?4788)

Comment: I figured out its definitely not an issue with the label. This is what I did. I created a boolean called 'clicked'. In the buyButton method I put 'clicked = YES;' so that the boolean changes to true. Then, I called '[self didLoadFromCCB];' and in that method I had an if statement, that stated if clicked = yes, then output an NSLog saying "yes". If clicked = no, output an NSLog saying "no". I ran the program and I received no from the NSLog.

Comment: @AlbertKornas in your defined labels, there's no ivar names `label`, how do you expect `label.string` working?

Comment: I just used the word 'label' for this post since it's easier to use. In the actual app I am using 'dogeAmount'. I redid this post and made an app with just this problem to make it a lot clearer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819273/how-to-change-labels-text-from-a-button-on-a-ccscrollview