# How to change labels text from a button on a CCScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I posted something very similar earlier, but I think the post was confusing so I'm redoing it.

Here's the setup. I am using SpriteBuilder. I have 2 CCB classes, MainScene.ccb and Scroll.ccb. The Scroll.ccb is a layer with a button on it. MainScene contains a CCScrollView and a CCLabelTTF. The CCScrollView is loading Scroll.ccb. The CCScrollView takes up half of the interface of MainScene, and on the other half is a CCColor that has the label on it.

When I click the button on the CCScrollView, I want the label on MainScene to change its text. The problem I am having is that the labels text doesn't change. However if I write an NSLog inside the buttons method to output text in the log, that DOES work.

I am including four pictures to help you better understand the situation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWPhz.jpg

I've been stuck on this for over a week now on my main project. I honestly have no clue what to do anymore, I've tried a bunch of things that didn't work, and I've run out of ideas.

EDIT: Okay so I got a little but further in debugging the issue. I inserted a label into the scrollview, and named it Label2. Under the buttons method I added 'Label2.string = @"Test"' and when I ran the program and clicked the button, the label on the scrollview changed. So it seems that when the button is being clicked, it looks in MainScene for the method and finds it, but it can't update a label on a different CCNode.

Comment: According to your EDIT info, I believe you have some problem link the label to your mainscene. have you link the `changeLabel` to your MainScene?

Comment: @highwing Yes, in SpriteBuilder I have it set as 'changeLabel' to doc root var and in the code I have it defined in the implementation and as a property in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have linked this method to the "click me" button ? Or maybe try to create a IBAction ?

```
-(void)testButton {

       changeLabel.String = @"Changed !";
}
```

OR

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender {

    changeLabel.String = @"Changed !";

}
```

i mean in your storyboard ( create the link with ctrl key and drag drop )

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes I have it linked. The IBAction didn't work, I don't think that works in Cocos2d if I remember correctly. Thanks though